# warnings.warn("DateTimeField %s received a naive datetime (%s)"

Tags: python, django, python-datetime

I use django simple-history to get history on my models
I then search the history results by date but I get the error below. How can I format the date?

```
RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField HistoricalIssue.history_date received a naive datetime (2022-04-13 10:34:32) while time zone support is active.
  warnings.warn("DateTimeField %s received a naive datetime (%s)"



def SearchByDate(request):
        date_search = request.POST['date-search']
        if date_search:
            admin_hist_search_results = Issue.history.filter(history_date=date_search)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, keep in mind that this is not an error, but "only" a warning. It mentions that the incoming timestamp (which you store in variable `date_search`) does not have timezone information, while you compare it with a timestamp  field (`history_date` on model `Issue`) that does have timezone information. This could potentially lead to issues.

If you know the timezone coming in from the request, you can add that information to the timestamp, for example:

```
import pytz

date_as_string = request.POST['date-search']
parsed_date = datetime.strptime(date_as_string, '%Y-%m-%d')
amsterdam_timezone = pytz.timezone('Europe/Amsterdam')
date_search = amsterdam_timezone.localize(parsed_date)
```

Comment: And @physicalattraction. I'd like to limit it to YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'

Comment: @fakeMake I forgot to add the date parsing step. I have updated the answer.